# Java Method Overloading error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have this getResult()  with slight variation in Input parameter. one  Mapvalue as string array for one  and string for anor .

But I am seeing a error: 
Wont overloading support generics?

```
public class App 
{

public void getResult(Map<String, String[]> map) {

}
public void getResult(Map<String, String> map) {

}
```

}

I am seeing this error:Method getResult(Map) has the same erasure getResult(Map) as another method in type App
I guess java is treating both as just Maps and so is this error.

what is  best approach to mimic this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to reformat.

Comment: yaa... some how some parts got vanished. I re formatted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the rules of overloading is that methods with type parameters cannot have the same signature *after erasure*. See [the Java Language Specification, §8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3). The relevant text from the spec is:

> It is a compile-time error if a type declaration T has a member method m<sub>1</sub> and there exists a method m<sub>2</sub> declared in T or a supertype of T such that: . . . The signature of m<sub>1</sub> or some method m<sub>1</sub> overrides (directly or indirectly) has the same erasure as the signature of m<sub>2</sub> or some method m<sub>2</sub> overrides (directly or indirectly).

Comment: So, is there any round about method to do that. half of the time, i dont need string array and half of the time i need it. So now all the Apps which are using this code have to write the code to convert single string to string array. Is there any solution for that

Comment: @ravi - You can give the methods different names. The only other approach, I think, would be to change the number and/or type (after erasure) of the arguments. For instance (and I don't recommend this, but I've seen it done, even in the Java API) you could add a dummy argument to one of the methods.

Answer (score 2):

Method parameters only respect the object's type, not any generics present on it.  Because of this, two methods with Map parameters will be considered the same, regardless of their generic types.